# Как сделать "обтекание" текстом картинки?

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-relativelayout

Работаю в `RelativeLayout`. Слева расположено `ImageView`, справа от него -
 `TextView`. Как сделать так, чтобы как только высота картинки заканчивалась, текст начал выводиться уже под картинкой слева от края экрана?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11494238/1991579

Answer (score 0):

Все просто! Просто берем и используем библиотеку [FlowTextView](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView)!